# Powershell - Use a "Contains"/"Match" function for hash maps

Tags: powershell

i wanna check if the following letters in the following words exists. My code is:

```
$testString="Word"
$illegalCharacter =@{Warning="a","b";Error="c","d"}

if($testString -match $illegalCharacter.Error){
Write-Host "WORKS!"
}
```

I guess "-contains" only works with Arrays - not Hash Maps. But why do this dont work?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I wrongly used `-contains` here first, but `-match` is what we want.

Another approach:

```
$testString = "Word"

$illegalCharacter = @{
    Warning = "a", "b"
    Error   = "c", "d"
}

if ($testString -match ($illegalCharacter.Error -join "|")) {
    Write-Host "WORKS!"
}
```

This build a string (example for `Error`: `"c|d"`) that is parsed as a regex meaning *either character c or d*

Comment: What if a regex special character like `|` is one of the illegal characters?

Comment: Worked! Thanks :)

Comment: The fact that this even works baffles me. `-contains` is not a regex operator. `$teststring -contains $illegalCharacter.Error -join "|"` alone returns `False`. This has to be a bug or some hidden PowerShell voodoo.

Comment: @AdminOfThings well I intended to use `-match` at first and was a bit surprised to realize it also worked with `-contains`

Comment: @AdminOfThings Explanation: `$testString -contains $illegalCharacter.Error` returns false which is cast to string for `-join` which returns "False". So what actually happens is: `if ("False") {}` and non-empty strings are evaluated as true. Basically the answer is wrong.

Comment: I wrote the answer with `-match` in mind, which has the wanted behavior in this case, so I've edited the answer. Thanks @marsze

Comment: Added parentheses

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a little bit different approach:

```
$testString="Word"
$illegalCharacter =@{Warning=@("a","b");Error= @("c","d")}

$illegalCharacter.Error | ForEach-Object { 
    if( $testString.Contains( $_ ) ) {
        Write-Host "WORKS!"; break 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to split up the string first to validate each character. You can do that with `.ToCharArray()`

My suggestion:

```
# Will throw for the first illegal character in the word
$testString.ToCharArray() | where { $illegalCharacter.Error -eq $_ } | foreach {
    throw "Illegal character: $_"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a case-sensitive search, then [Split(char[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) will be a concise solution.

```
$testString="Word"
$illegalCharacter =@{Warning=@("a","b");Error= @("c","d")}
if ($teststring.Split($illegalCharacter.Error).Count -gt 1) {
    Write-Host "WORKS!"
}
```

---

If you want to use the `-match` operator or `-cmatch` (case-sensitive match) operator, you will need to create a regex expression that includes alternations (`|`).

```
$testString="Word"
$illegalCharacter =@{Warning=@("a","b");Error= @("c","d")}
$regex = ($illegalcharacter.Error |% { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
if ($teststring -match $regex) {
    Write-Host "WORKS!"
}
```

The regex `|` character performs an `OR`. In this case, it will attempt to match `c` and alternatively `d` if `c` does not match. Special regex characters need to be escaped if you to match them literally. [Regex.Escape(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.8) escapes regex characters automatically.